# Why is device not showing the phone signal bars anymore?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-note-2, network-signal

It's been happening for a while now but I've just gotten around to posting this issue. I'm running Cyanogenmod 10.1 on my Galaxy Note 2 but one fine day, it stopped showing me the signal bars. I've even updated my ROM twice but it hasn't resolved the issue.

The phone calls and text messages work just fine but it always shows me that I don't have signal. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Would any of you know why this is happening and how I could resolve this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Other icons, especially E911, which is present on all phones and cannot be turned off, is also not there. Also, a WiFi icon should be there, if connected. So there's an issue of 3 potential missing icons. Do you have an app which uses notifications that may be blotting the icons out because it is sized incorrectly?

Comment: Isn't E911 specific to the USA ?

Comment: OK, so I'm not the NSA - I didn't really look up the OP's home. My comment about obscured icons is still a possibility.

Comment: @wbogacz, it's definitely not an icon issue. If you look at the answer below, the part about the dBm values being skewed is correct.

Comment: So How did you solve it?I'd really appreciate it if you answered your question so I won't need to ask it again.

Comment: @Behrooz, I haven't been able to solve the issue. I've tried digging around but nothing. I've updated my ROM multiple times but it doesn't change anything. DO let me know if you manage to solve it. Thx.

Comment: @MridangAgarwalla: The ALJ2/ALJ1/ALIH radios worked for me, but each has it's own set of problems, the phone calls and audio are very flaky and most of the times there is no audio in at least one direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely due incompatibilites between the RIL and the baseband/modem firmware. The RIL or the radio-interface layer are the libraries (shared-objects) that allow the phone to talk with the modem firmware. I found this issue on the Cyanogemod JIRA: https://jira.cyanogenmod.org/browse/CYAN-2172 
If you read the comments, you'll see that people have solved this issue by flashing a compatible firmware.

Since I'm now running Cyanogenmod 11, I dug around XDA and found a leaked 4.4 firmware for my device. It was packed in a CWM-flashable ZIP so I flashed it and voila.

Please remember to backup your device, your current modem/baseband and the RIL files. Flashing a new RIL isn't necessary always but helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually because you have very low signal (ie no bars) but are still connected to the network. Does it ever show any signal bars or is it just when you're in certain locations?

Can you provide a screenshot of the Status page (go to Settings > About > Status) which shows the signal strength? This might help to see how much signal you have.

EDIT: Your signal strength values look way off... On my Nexus 4 (and all other Android devices I've owned) these values are more like

> -85dbm 14asu

Did you flash a new radio when you went to CyanogenMod? I'd suggest looking for the [latest radio](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2044937) available for your device (probably start on [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=1790)) and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: please have a look at my revised question. This happens always, irrespective of the signal strength.

Comment: I haven't updated any radios. One day I simply used the inbuilt updater to update my ROM and this issue cropped up. I have absolutely no idea what radio I'm supposed to look for. :/ Is the radio different from the kernel?

Comment: I don't own a Note so I'm not sure which radio you'd need either. I'd suggest posting this question over at XDA as they will know a lot more about the specifics than most of us. I could be wrong with thinking it's a radio issue but it's a start. If you do get a solution over at XDA please remember to post it here as well for future reference.

Comment: Something is feeding nonsense to that indicator.  The numbers displayed are the maximum values for a signed 32-bit int and a unsigned char.  I've seen [reports of this on the LTE versions of the Galaxy S3](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=37526382&postcount=11370), though that bug was supposed to have been squashed back in February.

Comment: @Compro01, is there anything I can do about this? I'm not sure if Android has a safe mode but I guess that could be one solution. I've even tried wiping my Dalvik and Cache but that didn't help. Thank you.

Comment: @MridangAgarwalla - I'd advise either trying on [their IRC channel](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=cyanogenmod) or [filing a bug report](https://jira.cyanogenmod.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa).

Answer (score 0):

Its the data option you need to dial ##data# and Touch edit then enter your 6 digit msl codeyou get from your carrier. Then touch More then touch HDR/1X selection. From there you chose your preferred method it Probably was on evdo only but check CDMA or CDMA LTE if you get 4g. Now you touch back button til you asked to recycle phone after that you should see signal bar once restarted. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

New here, but here is the, on st least my systems answer. Under Settings, System UI Tuner, Status Bar, CELLULAR DATA must be on (slid to right). You can see the result immediately in Status Bar as you slide on/off.